# Finding the Fourier transform of this function

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have to find the Fourier transform of $[3^{(-k)}]u(-k-1)$

so the Fourier transform $X(f)= x(k) e^{(-j\cdot 2\pi f k)}$.

I have $(1/3)^{k}  u[-k-1]$

The problem is, I know that the Fourier transform of $(1/3)^{k} u[k-1]$ is $$[(1/3) e^{-j\cdot 2\pi f}]\over[1-(1/3) e^{-j\cdot 2\pi f}]$$

but not when we have $-k$ instead of $k$?

Comment: Please use the $\LaTeX$ support, my eyes hurt.

Comment: Could you please edit your question according to [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) Mathjax tutorial? Also, explain your notation.